# Optimal function javascript to eliminate duplicates

Tags: javascript

So let's say i have a variable that stores a big string and where the 
 is the separator to the next word. whats the best way to eliminate duplicate words using the 
 as the indicator.

So imagine we have this:

```
var notRemoved= " I am col 1 
I am col 2
I am col 11 
I am col 1 
I am col 2
```

And the result should be like this:

```
var removed= " I am col 1 
I am col 2
I am col 11 "
```

Comment: Please share a [mcve] of what you have already tried?

Comment: is `notRemoved` an array or a string with lines break?

Comment: The example input and output both throw syntax errors

Comment: ``[...new Set(notRemoved.split("\n"))].join("\n")``

Answer (score 0):

This one has answer here : [Get all unique values in a JavaScript array (remove duplicates)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1960473/get-all-unique-values-in-a-javascript-array-remove-duplicates)

Try this:

```
function onlyUnique(value, index, self) {
  return self.indexOf(value) === index;
}

// usage example:
var a = ['a', 1, 'a', 2, '1'];
var unique = a.filter(onlyUnique);

console.log(unique); // ['a', 1, 2, '1']
```

Comment: What array? There is no array in the question!

Comment: If you're linking to another answer, please flag the question as a duplicate.

Comment: @Ingenious_Hans they're different types. They're not that similar. Strings are immutable for example

Answer (score 0):

The best way to perfom what you want is by :

- Splitting your `String` into an `array`
- Removing the duplicates (for example using a `Set`)
- Re-creating a string using the `join` method.

```js
const notRemoved = `I am col 1 
I am col 2
I am col 11 
I am col 1 
I am col 2`



function removeDuplicatesFromString(str){
  const splitArray = notRemoved.split('\n')
  const arrayWithoutDuplicates = [...new Set(splitArray)];

  return arrayWithoutDuplicates.join('\n')
}


console.log(removeDuplicatesFromString(notRemoved))
```

**Note** : This can also be done using one line :

```js
let removed = [...new Set(notRemoved.split('\n')].join('\n');
```

### Documentation

[split method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split)

[Set](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set)

[join method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join)

Comment: Hello. for some reason i have a error in the line where i declare new Set(array). is this related with the fact im using vanilla javascript? do i need to import anything? im relative new into javascript
the error im getting

accordion.js?id=ab61bbd215ed0fc1: 137:32 Syntax error

Comment: The snippet provided in my aswer uses vanilla javascript so the error might come from somewhere else. It seems like it's from `accordion.js`